# Grunt SASS compiling backslashed content to faulty unicode glyph

Tags: css, unicode, sass, gruntjs

We have the following code in a SASS project:

```
.icon-mail:before { content: '\e800'; }
```

Which gets compiled into this code by Grunt SASS on *some* development computers:

```
.icon-mail:before {
    content: "";
```

Which then breaks the display in browsers (tested Chrome & Firefox).

To confuse things it compiles as expected on the designers OSX Macs, but not on the developers Ubuntu machines.

What's expected & works:

```
.icon-mail:before { 
    content: '\e800';
```

I found this issue in Github which looks similar - but there's no clear fix: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/620

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue before, and after a lot of searching end up with use of [this](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1395#issuecomment-57483844) suggestion. I've modified it to be more generic and it results into this function that works fine for me in multiple projects. Compiles well on Windows / Linux / OS X.

```
/// Convert given unicode character code into unicode char reference
///
/// @example scss 
///   unicode("e655"); 
///   // "\e655"
///
/// @source - [@Stephn-R](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1395#issuecomment-57483844)
/// @param string $str   Unicode character code to convert
/// @return string
@function unicode($str) {
    @if (str-slice($str, 1, 1) != str-slice("\\", 1, 1)) {
        $str: unquote(str-insert($str, str-slice("\\", 1, 1), 1));
    }
    @return unquote("\"")+$str+unquote("\"")
}
```